# C - passing 2-D array to function prints only first row

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, printf, subroutine

I want to pass a static 2-D array to a function, but when I try to print the matrix in this function, it prints only the first row. Is there anything wrong while passing parameters to the function? If I try to print the matrix in the main program, print successfully shows the complete matrix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int LD=10;

int diagdom(int,int,float(*)[]);

int main(){
    float A[LD][LD];
    int N,LD,i,j,B;
    scanf("%d",&N);
    for (i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            scanf("%f",&A[i][j]);
        }
    }

    B=diagdom(LD,N,A);
    printf("%d \n",B);
    return 0;
}

int diagdom(int LD, int N, float A[][LD]){
    int k,h;
    int i,j,cost;
    cost =-1;
    i=-1;

    for (i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<N;j++){
            printf("%f \n",A[i][j]);
        }
    }

    do {
        i=i+1;
        k=0;
        h=0;
        for (j=0;j<N;j++){

            if(j==i){
                h=abs(A[i][j]);
                printf("%d. \n", h);
            }
            else{
                k=k+abs(A[i][j]);
                }
        }
            if(h<k){
                cost=i;                    
            }
        } while(!(i==N || cost!=-1));
        return cost;
}
```

Comment: Why declare the function `diagdom(int,int,float(*)[])` differently from the definition `diagdom(int LD, int N, float A[][LD])`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your main you redeclared LD on the method scope, which means LD is now 0(most likely) in main. If you remove the LD declaration in the main, it should fix the problem.

change `int N,LD,i,j,B;` to `int N, i, j, B;`